# WARNING: the following functions are not known to be defined: x-display-pixel-width, x-display-pixel-height, x-show-tip. emacs-nox

Tags: terminal-emacs, emacs-nox

*I'm using Emacs in terminal mode.* I am not getting any error, what I am getting is just a warning, `the following functions are not known to be defined: x-display-pixel-width, x-display-pixel-height, x-show-tip`.

I am using `emacs-nox` but I am doing it in `WSL` (`Windows linux subsytem`) my `init.el` and `myInit.org` give not errors using `emacs` in `ubuntu`, but I was forced to change to windows because of my supervisor I already tried `emacs` in windows and I am facing problems with some packages like `Aspell` therefore I decied to use the `WSL` but i am getting such previous mentioned warning.

What is that? I know I can ignore it, but is there any reason of the warning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See update at the end of this answer.  I edited your question to state the most important bit of info, based on your adding tag `terminal-emacs` to it: **You're using Emacs in terminal mode.**

---

1. You can likely ignore those warnings.
2. However, you should *not* see those warnings on MS Windows, I believe.
3. What happens if you do `C-h f x-display-pixel-width`? On MS Windows, Emacs 27.2 (the latest release), started with `emacs -Q`, I see the function described fine.

---

Your question is incomplete. What Emacs version are you using?
Where/when do you see those warnings? I assume it's when you byte-compile some file (those are byte-compiler warnings), but please specify (provide a recipe to reproduce).

Do you see those warnings if you start Emacs on MS Windows using `emacs -Q` (no init file)? If not, bisect your init file to find the culprit.

---

Oops. I see now, from a tag you used, that you're using Emacs in terminal mode. There is no support for pixel-granular functions in terminal mode. That's your answer. The library you byte-compiled likely won't be able to support some pixel-relevant behavior. (It may be able to do other things, however.)

See the Emacs manual, node [Glossary](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Glossary.html), entry **Text Terminal**:

> A text terminal, or character terminal, is a display that is limited to displaying text in character units.  Such a ***terminal cannot control individual pixels** it displays.  Emacs supports a subset of display features on text terminals.*

Comment: @NickD Thank you for your reply look i am using `emacs 26.3` i installed using `emacs-nox`. Yes those warnings appear only when i compiled my `init.el` and `myInit.org` files for the first time . However, if i start `emacs-nox` with no file, lets say a `scratch` file, those warnings no longer appear, those warnings are `Warning (bytecomp)`. As i mentioned before i am using in terminal in other words (NO GUI). Therefore, those warnings can be neglected right?. EDIT: Thanks @Drew

Comment: Correction: @Drew answered your question, not me: I just fixed a typo.

Comment: One more thing, i loaded `counsel` using the next line `(use-package counsel)`. Also everything goes right, but also another warning appear, `Warning (bytecomp): Unused lexical variable ‘tramp-archive-enabled'`. Also this warning can be neglected right?.

Comment: Please don't pose additional questions in comments. Post a separate question for it. Thx.

Comment: @Drew Thank you very much, you are totally right. Was my fault. i must not do that. By the way ill this one, as solved.

Comment: No problem. Please do pose a separate question, if you'd like answers.